# How to implement integral image on sliding window detection?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, matlab-cvst

I am doing a project to detect people in crowd using HOG-LBP. I want to make it for real-time application. I've read in some references, integral image/histogram can increase the speed of the performance from sliding window detection. I want to ask, how to implement integral image on my sliding window detection:

here is the code for integral image from matlab:

```
A = (cumsum(cumsum(double(img)),2));
```

and here my sliding window detection code:

```
im = strcat ('C:\Documents\Crowd_PETS09\S1\L1\Time_13-57\View_001\frame_0150.jpg');
im = imread (im);


figure (1), imshow(im);

win_size= [32, 32];

[lastRightCol lastRightRow d] = size(im);

counter = 1;
%% Scan the window by using sliding window object detection
% this for loop scan the entire image and extract features for each sliding window
% Loop on scales (based on size of the window)
for s=1
    disp(strcat('s is',num2str(s)));
    X=win_size(1)*s;
    Y=win_size(2)*s;
    for y = 1:X/4:lastRightCol-Y
        for x   = 1:Y/4:lastRightRow-X

            %get four points for boxes
            p1  = [x,y];
            p2  = [x+(X-1), y+(Y-1)];
            po  = [p1; p2] ;

            % cropped image based on the four points
            crop_px    = [po(1,1) po(2,1)];
            crop_py    = [po(1,2) po(2,2)];

            topLeftRow = ceil(min(crop_px));
            topLeftCol = ceil(min(crop_py));

            bottomRightRow = ceil(max(crop_px));
            bottomRightCol = ceil(max(crop_py));

            cropedImage    = im(topLeftCol:bottomRightCol,topLeftRow:bottomRightRow,:);

            %Get the feature vector from croped image
            HOGfeatureVector{counter}= getHOG(double(cropedImage));
            LBPfeatureVector{counter}= getLBP(cropedImage);
            LBPfeatureVector{counter}= LBPfeatureVector{counter}';
            boxPoint{counter} = [x,y,X,Y];
            counter = counter+1;
            x = x+2;

        end
    end
end
```

where should i put the integral image code?

i am really appreciate, if someone can help me to figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't use matlab for real time

Comment: 1) A `)` is missing. 2) The best way to find an implementation is to read more books and learn more about what you are working on.

Comment: why? but I think, it will still work with matlab, wont it? do you have any idea for it? @zenpoy

Comment: oo yeah it is just small mistake, forget while wrote it. I have read some references and understood. but it seems hard for me when i should apply on the code. that's why i asked to some experts, hopefully they can help me. @Yvon

Comment: I didn't say it won't work. But you should expect a nice x5 to x100 performance boost when implementing the sane algorithm in c++. Espe

Answer (score 2):

The integral image is most suited for the Haar-like features. Using it for HOG or LBP would be tricky.  I would suggest to first get your algorithm working, and then think about optimizing it.

By the way, the Computer Vision System Toolbox includes the `extractHOGFeatures` function, which would be helpful.  Here's an [example of training a HOG-SVM classifier to recognize hand-written digits](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html).  Also there is a `vision.PeopleDetector` object, which uses a HOG-SVM classifier to detect people.  You could either use it directly for your project, or use it to evaluate performance of your own algorithm.